# Using XSLT base-uri with Saxon collection function

Tags: xslt, saxon

I want to batch process all the XML files in a directory, generating output filenames based on a value in each XML. I am using the Saxon collection function in conjunction with the base-uri function, but I am having difficulty accessing each URI individually.

Edit: the below stylesheet gives the error message: "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of base-uri()"

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:param name="input-dir" select="'file:///C:/path/to/directory'"/>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:variable name="input-docs" select="collection(iri-to-uri(concat($input-dir, '?select=*.xml')))"/>
        <xsl:variable name="old-filename" select="base-uri($input-docs)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="new-filename" select="item[@name = 'LogNo']/text"/>

        <xsl:for-each select="$old-filename">
            <xsl:result-document href="concat ($new-filename, '.xml')">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit: for completeness, I've added the two command line prompts that I've attempted. I'm not sure if the path to the input directory should be specified in the stylesheet or in the command line.

```
 java -jar "C:\path\to\saxon.jar" -it:main -o:"C:\path\to\renamed\XML"  -xsl:"C:\path\to\stylesheet.xslt" 

 java -jar "C:\path\to\saxon.jar" -s:"C:\path\to\input\XML" -o:"C:\path\to\renamed\XML"  -xsl:"C:\path\to\stylesheet.xslt"
```

Comment: Is the work done, when you put the "concat ($new-filename, '.xml')" into `{}`?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow... where would the curly braces go?

Comment: uL1 is suggesting to use an AVT (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) so it would look like `href="{concat($new-filename, '.xml')}"`. However, the context of your `for-each` is going to be a string (`$old-filename`); maybe you want to select `$input-docs` instead?

Comment: I tried adding the curly braces <xsl:result-document href="{concat($new-filename, '.xml')}"> and changing the  context of the for-each to <xsl:for-each select="base-uri($input-docs)">, but I'm still getting an error message. Before, the error message said "A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of base-uri()". Now the error message says "The context item is absent"

Answer (score 0):

It often becomes clear where your errors are if you follow the discipline of always declaring the data type of your variables.

For example, it's evident that the declaration of `input-docs` should have type `as="document-node()*"`. But that's clearly not a valid argument to a call on `base-uri()`.

So it's obvious what's wrong with your code (and indeed, the error message says it clearly). Correcting it is more difficult, because you haven't told us what you want to achieve. But the normal logic would be something like this:

```
<xsl:template name="main">
    <xsl:variable name="input-docs" 
      select="collection(iri-to-uri(concat($input-dir, '?select=*.xml')))" 
      as="document-node()*"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$input-docs">
      <xsl:variable name="new-filename" 
                    select="item[@name = 'LogNo']/text"         
                    as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:result-document href="concat ($new-filename, '.xml')">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

If you want to get the base-uri of the documents in the collection you should probably be doing this inside the xsl;for-each - but I'm not sure what you actually want to do with the information. (Also, using `document-uri()` might be more appropriate than `base-uri()`, but the distinction is subtle).

Comment: I'd like to output one XML file for every input file in the directory, but I want the filename to be based on an element within each file. I'm now getting the error message: Error on line 6 of LogNo.xslt:
  XTTE0570: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable
  $input-docs (document-node(), document-node(), ...)
A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the value of variable $input-docs (document-node(), document-node(), ...)

Comment: @b00kgrrl, are you sure you have `as="document-node()*"` (with the asterisk `*` after `document-node()`) when you get that error?

Comment: When I add the asterisk, I don't get that error any more. I am now able to output one XML file per input file, but the new-filename is not getting picked up. The problem seems to be in the command line. The input directory is not getting picked up. This is what I have:    java -jar "C:\path\to\saxon.jar" -it:main -o:"C:\path\to\renamed\XML"  -xsl:"C:\path\to\stylesheet.xslt"

Comment: If `$input-dir` is defined as a global stylesheet parameter, then you can/should supply a value for it on the command line e.g as `input-dir=file:///my/dir`

Comment: If I do this at the command line: java -jar C:\path\to\jar -it:main input-dir="C:\path\to\input\XML" -o:"C:\path\to\fixed\XML"  -xsl:"C:\path\to\stylesheet.xslt"

I get an error: "Output is a directory, but input is not"

(The input directory does exist.)

Comment: The -o option should be the file (not directory) where you want the principal output of the stylesheet to go (even if it's empty). The href attribute of xsl:result-document will be interpreted relative to this location.

Comment: I changed the -o option to a file (although I have successfully used a directory for the -o option in the past) and I percent-encoded the input directory, as suggested here: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17221566/xsl-2-0-transform-xml-files-while-preserving-folder-structure). This is resulting in a single file that is empty except for the XML declaration.

Comment: Use the -t option to check that secondary results aren't being written somewhere unexpected.

Comment: The NamePool shows 6 URIs. I'm not sure what "processing (no source document)" means. Here are the relevant bits: 
Processing  (no source document) initial template = main
NamePool contents: 3 entries in 3 chains. 6 URIs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128286/discussion-between-b00kgrrl-and-michael-kay).